# Why does Infinitest keep giving me SocketExceptions and what can I do about it?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, infinitest, eclipse-jee

I'm running Infinitest in Eclipse Neon (version numbers below).  Except it won't run and in the Infinitest Console, I get this message over and over:

```
Error occurred during test run
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:90)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:380)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:236)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:469)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:239)
    at org.infinitest.testrunner.TestRunnerProcess.main(TestRunnerProcess.java:79)
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

Infinitest 5.2.0

EDIT:
I switched projects and got this:

```
Error occurred during test run
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:90)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:380)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:236)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:469)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:239)
    at org.infinitest.testrunner.TestRunnerProcess.main(TestRunnerProcess.java:79)
```

Similar, but not the same.  I added it as perhaps it could help.

Comment: I did a generic "Check for updates" but it didn't find anything that needed updated, so that didn't help.

Comment: So, it's now failing maybe half the time?  Sometimes it works, sometimes I get the error.

Comment: It stopped failing for a long time.  Now it's failing again.  I cannot determine a pattern.

Comment: I updated my eclipse to the latest version.  It'll work for a while then stop.  Then work.  Then stop.  Sometimes rebooting helps, sometimes not.